# onPositionChanged handler of gmaps marker scope issue

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, react-google-maps

I try to update the current position of a draggable marker of the react-google-maps wrapper and pass these values back to the parent.
My problem is, that in `onMarkerPositionChange` `this` is either the FindLocationMarker class or the marker itself, depending on how the function is invoked.
`onPositionChanged={() => this.onMarkerPositionChange()}` was my other option.

I need both, the marker for the position and the class for the function in props.
In the provided example, `this` is the marker.
`evt` is undefined, I know.

How can i provide both, the class scope and the marker, to the function?

```
class FindLocationMarker extends Component {

  onMarkerPositionChange = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt);
    let lat = this.position.lat();
    let lng = this.position.lng();

    this.props.handleMarkerPositionChange(lat, lng);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Marker
          position={this.props.position}
          draggable
          onPositionChanged={this.onMarkerPositionChange}
        />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

export default FindLocationMarker;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long discussion below I decided to update my answer for future issues with https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps Marker.jsx component.

If you want to get the position of the marker onPositionChange you need to:

1. Store the marker in your refs
2. Listen to the onPositionChange event and then access the position of the marker in your refs.

Example:

```
onPositionChanged() {
    const position = this.marker.getPosition();

    // do something with position
}

render() {
    return <Marker
        onPositionChanged={ ::this.onPositionChanged }
        ref={input => this.marker = input}
    />
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it working. The only way to pass the Marker is to use a non-arrow-function in the `onPositionChanged` and define `onMarkerPositionChange` as non-arrow-function. When I then bind `this` to it, the Marker object gets overridden. Parameters are undefined, always(!!)

Comment: Is the Marker component yours? The Marker is the problem, not your implementation. Its behavior is very strange...

Comment: No it's not. Take a look:
https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/components/Marker.jsx

Comment: Ok this lib seems very confusing and anti-react to me, but ok... The lib is using this lib: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker . The event that is firing onPositionChanged is position_changed. The API doc says that there are no more arguments applied to the function - this is what we observed. So I had a closer look into the Map.jsx itself and it has a broad API of getters. The one you should test is getPosition(). How to? Render the Map with ref={input => this.marker = input} and in onMarkerPositionChange try this.marker.getPosition()

Comment: Thanks Tobias, that works pretty well. I found a similar but slightly more complecated solution. But your approach is cleaner and I prefer this one. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Ok great. Updated my answer :-)